# UINavigationBar moving under status bar when another viewController hides status bar

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationbar, uistatusbar

The problem is simple, the Profile `viewController` has a `NavigationBar` just under the status bar.
I push another `viewController` on top of the current one.
This new `viewController` hides the status bar.

When I go back to the Profile `viewController`, the `navigationBar` has moved up by the size of the status bar height.

I tried to force a layout refresh in my `viewWillAppear` but it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement `viewDidDisappear` in that presented viewcontroller and show status bar again before come to profileview controller.

```
  override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {


    UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarHidden(false, withAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation.Fade)
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you! that's ALMOST the fix, in fact, it works if I use viewWillDisappear but not in viewDidDisappear, but I would prefer to manage the layout in the profile view controller itself if possible. Because if somebody else create another view hiding the status bar again... it will bug...

Comment: You're welcome... :) This is the right way. If somebody hides status bar in any VC then he must implement viewdiddisappear or willdisappear to shows it again. this is the only standard solution. If you manage profileview, at this time this is profile view but somebody hide status bar in another view and it's base view is not profileview then? so it is better to implement willdisappear or diddisappear to show statusbar again

Comment: can you update your answer with viewWillDisappear as it actually doesn't work with viewDidDisappear(). You were the one to put me on the right track. It's quite sad that it is the only way to do it though...

Comment: @Mikael : Updated answer with `viewWillDisappear`... :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this below code,

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(navigationController?.navigationBarHidden == false, animated: false)
}
```

hope its helpful

Answer (score 0):

add code in plist file hide status bar in your app:

```
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```