# UINavigationBar moves under status bar when using swipe back gesture from status bar hidden viewController

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationbar, uistatusbar

The problem is simple, the Profile viewController has a NavigationBar just under the status bar. I push another viewController on top of the current one. This new viewController hides the status bar.

When I go back USING A SWIPE BACK GESTURE to the Profile viewController, the navigationBar has moved up by the size of the status bar height.

[image]

The related question is [UINavigationBar moving under status bar when another viewController hides status bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37437075/uinavigationbar-moving-under-status-bar-when-another-viewcontroller-hides-status)

Any ideas?

Comment: This answer should work in both! Are you manually implementing swipegesture regognizer or saying about default swipe to go back?

Answer (score 0):

Actually,

in that case too, using the following also works.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
```

Calling this in viewWillDisappear of the second view controller solves the issue.
The main View controller contains a main view and I add a tableView in within the view (the blue-ish color on the screenshot is the header of the tableview).

Somehow, this composition doesn't layout really well... I have no idea why.
Somebody wrote that to avoid this kind of layout issues, using a scrollView as a container makes the trick but I can't add tableViews to a scrollView...

If anybody has an explanation about why this layout problem happens, I'd be happy about it.